# How to create a scrollable table with fixed headers where the width should be auto?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a table containing more than 70 columns and the width cannot be defined as only user updates data into it.

I need the header position: fixed and aligned properly with the table. Both header and the table should be scrollable vertically & horizontally. Importantly width:auto

Below are html & css codings Unable to add all the codes as its a huge table. I have searched as much as possible. Unable to find a solution for these three requirements at once. Hope someone can give me a solution.

```
table {
  z-index: 1;
  table-layout: auto;
}

table thead {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #cecece;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 37px;
}

td,
th {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

html

```
<html>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:11px; font-family:verdana;">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!--1-->
      <th>Site ID</th>
      <!--2-->
      <th>Site Name</th>
      <!--3-->
      <th>Site Address</th>
      <!--4-->
      <th>Project Type</th>
      <!--5-->
      <th>Implementation Requested Date </th>
      <!--6-->
      <th>Target Completion Date</th>
      <!--7-->
      <th>Vendor</th>
      <!--8-->
      <th>ESR No</th>
      <!--9-->
      <th>Contact Details</th>
      <!--10-->
      <th>Engineer</th>
      <!--11-->
      <th>Account Manager</th>
      <!--12-->
      <th>Sent to Contractors for Quotation</th>
      <!--13-->
      <th>Expected Date</th>
      <!--14-->
      <th>SO Approval for JFS Requested</th>
      <!--15-->
      <th>Expected Date</th>
      <!--16-->
      <th>SO Approval for JFS Received</th>
      <!--17-->
      <th>Expected Date</th>
      <!--18-->
      <th>JFS Done</th>
      <!--19-->
      <th>Expected Date</th>
      <!--20-->
      <th>Drawing Submited OFN to SAQ</th>
      <!--21-->
      <th>Expected Date</th>
      <!--22-->
      <th>SO Approval for Drawing</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <?php
    //$i = 1;
    while ($fiberexcel=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){
        $A1=$fiberexcel['SiteID0']; //1
        $A2=$fiberexcel['SiteName1'];   //2
        $A3=$fiberexcel['SiteAddress2'];    //3
        $A4=$fiberexcel['ProjectType3'];    //4
        $ReqDate4=$fiberexcel['ReqDate4'];  //5
        $A6=$fiberexcel['TargetDate5']; //6
        $A7=$fiberexcel['Vendor6']; //7
        $A8=$fiberexcel['ESRNo7'];  //8
        $A9=$fiberexcel['Contact8'];    //9
        $A10=$fiberexcel['Engineer9'];  //10
        $A11=$fiberexcel['AM10'];   //11
        $A12=$fiberexcel['Quotation11'];
        $test=$fiberexcel['test input text']; //12
        $A13=$fiberexcel['ExpectDateQuotation12'];  //13
        $ApprovalJFSRequest13=$fiberexcel['ApprovalJFSRequest13'];  //14
        $A15=$fiberexcel['ExpectDateJFSRequest14']; //15
        $ApprovalJFSReceived15=$fiberexcel['ApprovalJFSReceived15'];    //16
        $A17=$fiberexcel['ExpectDateJFSReceived16'];    //17
        $JFSDone17=$fiberexcel['JFSDone17'];    //


    echo "<form action=Display.php method=post>";
    //echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"  .$fiberexcel['SiteID0'] ." </td>";
    echo "<td>"  .$fiberexcel['SiteName1'] ." </td>";
    echo "<td>"  .$fiberexcel['SiteAddress2'] ." </td>";

    </table>
```

Comment: 1. I suggest you move away from PHP, especially for something this simple. 2. Use "overflow" in your CSS and you can set the scrolling behavior, e.g. place your headers within thead, then in tbody you have your entries, and set overflow:auto for tbody.

Comment: I tried that @SimonHyll. since the width:auto; the tbody & thead is not aligning properly.

Comment: After understanding your needs better I'll say that making this happen with pure CSS is a nightmare. I'd suggest using a javascript based solution where you e.g. calculate the widths of all the headers and set the corresponding cells widths to match it, after that you can pretty much just use overflow as usual.

Comment: Edited my answer. No widths used, apart from width: 100%; on the container